# What is the syntax error "Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket."?

Tags: matlab, syntax-error, octave

The following code produces an error

```
n=4; 
p=3; 
x =-(pi./2); 
y=-(pi./2);
z=-(pi./2); 

%Now, define the matrix v_k  
v_k = [sin(x).*sin(y).*sin(z), ...
    1-(1-cos(x))(sin(y).^2.*sin(z).^2), ...
    -(1-cos(x))(sin(y).^2.*sin(z).*cos(z)), ...
    -(1-cos(x))(sin(y).*sin(z).*cos(y)); ...
    sin(x).*sin(y).*cos(z), ...
    -(1-cos(x))(sin(y).^2.*sin(z).*cos(z)), ...
    1-(1-cos(x))(sin(y).^2.*cos(z).^2), ...
    -(1-cos(x))(sin(y).*cos(y).*cos(z)); ...
    sin(x).*cos(y), ...
    -(1-cos(x))(sin(y).*sin(z).*cos(y)), ...
    -(1-cos(x))(sin(y).*cos(y).*cos(z)), ...
    1-(1-cos(x))(cos(y).^2); ...
    cos(x), ...
    -sin(x).*sin((y).*sin(z),...
    -sin(x).*sin(y).*cos(z),...
    -sin(x).*cos(y)];
```

The error shown is :

```
Error: File: test.m Line: 9 Column: 17 Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

Or alternatively, if run from the command window

```
v_k = [sin(x).*sin(y).*sin(z), ...
    1-(1-cos(x))(sin(y).^2.*sin(z).^2)]
     1-(1-cos(x))(sin(y).^2.*sin(z).^2)]
                 ↑
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

Comment: Write your code within the body of your question instead of providing links to other sites

Comment: @SardarUsama The code is hopelessly long, you can see in the link provided, shall I send a screenshot?

Comment: Then read how to create a [MCVE] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: If you can create a screenshot, you should be able to copy and paste the code. Screenshots of code are not useful, because to run it, I have to retype everything myself. If you are getting an error message, as implied by your title, you should also copy and paste the error message into your question.

Comment: @SardarUsama I hope you may read now

Comment: @Cecilia I hope you get the error shown

Comment: Please ***DO NOT ADD IMAGES***. Just add the code itself. How difficult can it be to simply copy-past code instead of going through all the effort of uploading a screenshot?

Comment: @Adriaan sorry, but I am unable to copy from my workspace. I think this is because I am on an iPad

Comment: Then hand-enter it here for all I care. Images of code are not accepted here. I'm not going to try to hand-copy all your equations out of my free will to help you. I want to be able to copy your code and see the error directly there.

Comment: Vidyarthi, I have edited your question for you to include the code in the proper format. I have also changed the title to be more descriptive. In the future, please include all relevant information as text, not images. And try to make your example as small as possible. I only needed two of the elements of your matrix to throw the error not all 15.

Comment: @Cecilia either don't edit, or copy their entire code. I have rejected your suggested edit, because it misses the majority of the code (even though that is irrelevant)

Comment: @Adriaan Alright, that's fair. I've added the rest of the matrix provided in the screenshot.

Comment: Of course, the OP has been editing the code all this time so there's no guarantee that the code that's in the original link is the code that's causing the error. @vidyarthi This is why you need to put the *actual* code *in text format* into the question. Changing the code that causes the problem doesn't help anybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a closing parenthesis, at least, in the second to last line where you have `.*sin((y).*sin(z),` and missing a `*` (or another operator) between your `)(` in several lines. In MATLAB `(A)(B)` is not `A*B`.

Comment: should we put * sign between brackets, dosent matlab multiply two brackets diectly?

Comment: yes, that is correct. It doesn't know that `)(` means multiply.

Comment: Also, could you please mark the check if this solves your problem? Thanks!

Comment: yes, surely. But, let me check once again

Comment: should we put .*or * between brackets

Comment: [Depends](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html). If you have matrices and want to do elementwise operations, use `.`.

Comment: I think the problem in new lines. I do not know about octave, but matlab requires ... (three dots) at end of line, to continue expression on next one.

Comment: @BorisT There are no newlines in the original code. Kinda hard to tell in the image, I know.